# XmlNode indexer result if there is no such element

Tags: c#, xml, indexing

I am writing code that needs to get the first element from a node with a given name, or put simply use the `XmlNode.Item` indexer. The problem I noticed is the documentation conveniently **fails** to specify what happens if there is no such child element in this node. It is known that `Dictionary` throws an exception, and `XmlAttributeCollection` is kind enough to mention that it will return `null`, so which should I prepare for, an exception or `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some code to test this, it appears that it returns null. Here's the code snippet I used.

```
const string xmlData = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<testRoot xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
    <ExampleData isData=""true"" testString=""Hello World!"">
        content
    </ExampleData>
</testRoot>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
var item = doc["foo"];
Assert.IsNull(item);
```